# Is it possible to have a not have a "do not bump to the homepage" buttton?

Tags: feature-request, editing

Is it possible to have a not have a "do not bump to the homepage" buttton in the editing interface? Sometimes one edits a post simply to improve grammar in a minor way that does not change the understandibility of the text in no great way. However, those rather archival edits still bump posts to the homepage which only debumps the active questions that are supposed to be bumped. There is a dillema that your improvement of a post de-improves the front page.

PS: This might belong to SE meta. If so please let me know so we can migrate it.

Comment: Definitely one for Meta.SE I think - it's not something we can change on a site-specific basis.

Answer (score 3):

There's a discussion [on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122567/allow-non-bumping-minor-edits-but-review-them-on-review) that's still open. I'm not sure whether we'd consider this. Review queues aren't the best solution to a lot of problems, particularly when there's risk to a site.

In general, we don't want to do this because, while *you* may have every intention of only fixing minor grammatical issues, there's too much risk of vandalism without review. Having the post appear on the front page acts as that review. You or other users see it and check it out to see what changed.

On top of that, we hope that it acts as a deterrent. People who would make these sorts of problematic edits likely do not because they know that they'll likely be caught.

There may be other ways we can manage this in the future but, for now, all edits will bump the post.

Comment: There is one thing which already mitigates the vandalism aspect, that being any user under 1k rep gets reviewed. Most of these types of edits would, IMHO, come from these types of users. A very easy way to *further* mitigate this would be to not allow the "button" to appear to users under the 1k rep in the first place. Yes, anyone over 1k rep can directly edit a post, however someone with over 1k rep has invested time and energy into the site and is given the direct edit privilege. If we trust them to do direct edits, we should also trust them to not do silly things like vandalize a post.